# Embed image as icon with Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am creating an Excel XLSX document with Apache POI and I want to embed an image on each row, on a particular column. The other columns have text data, usually a single line.

The problem is that the images are large and overlap, making the file not easily readable.

I have the following code now:

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(content.toString());
byte[] imageBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
int picId = sheet.getWorkbook().addPicture(imageBytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);
inputStream.close();
CreationHelper helper = sheet.getWorkbook().getCreationHelper();
Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
anchor.setCol1(cell.getColumnIndex());
anchor.setRow1(cell.getRowIndex());
Picture pict = drawing.createPicture(anchor,picId);
pict.resize();
```

I would like to embed the images as an icon, if possible, that you would be able to double click to open.

Thanks in advance for your support!

Comment: Shrink your image before embedding it?

Comment: I would like the user to be able to see the full image eventually, by clicking it or something.

Comment: Does Microsoft Excel even support that? If so, how would you go about doing it in Excel itself?

Comment: Insert object -> From file and tick the "Display as icon" checkbox